# Allow alpha-numeric and certain special characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to restrict characters other than

```
[A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, @, #]
```

I need to wrap this inside "**onkeypress**" and "**onblur**" to handle **copy/paste** values. so, if there is any **regex** for the above mentioned scenario, Plz update on this.

**So far, I have something like this**

```
$(document).on('keypress onblur', "#Login", function () {
var checkString = $("#Login").val();
if (checkString != "") {
    if (/[^A-Za-z_@#\d]/.test(checkString)) {
        alert("Please enter only letter and numeric characters");
        $("#Login").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

The above code didnt work properly with the specified condition.

Comment: The event is `blur` and not `onblur`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test(string)
```

`[0-9@_#]+` will match all the numbers with allowed special characters
`|` OR
`[a-zA-Z@_#]` will match all the alphabets with allowed special characters.

[image: Regex Visualization]

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3cec10zr/)

```js
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("Tushar") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('Tushar')); // True
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("Tushar@#") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('Tushar@#')); // True
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("12345") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('12345')); // True
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("12@#_447") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('12@#_447')); // True
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("tushar1234") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('tushar1234')); // False
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("tushar_1234") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('tushar_1234')); // False
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("tushar@1234") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('tushar@1234')); // False
document.write('<br />/^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test("123@tushar") = ' + /^([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)$/.test('123@tushar')); // False
```

Comment: I need to allow user to enter full alpha or full numeric or alphanumeric with certain special characters. No restriction to enter only alphanumeric.

Comment: Any restriction on where special symbols should occur? Like at beginning or end

Comment: No more restrictions other than what i specified before.

Comment: if (/([0-9@_#]+|[a-zA-Z@_#]+)/.test("as2$")) { return true;}. The above condition still return true.

Comment: Forget to add ^ and $. Check now

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't put ^ in your regex otherwise you'll only target strings that starts with your pattern and not thoses that contain it.